# Is there an add-on for paid "premium" entry purchase/upgrade subscription management?

Tags: add-on, membrr, subscriptions

I have a large EE site. Its main purpose is as a directory. Listings (entries) in the directory can be created for free by any member. But I want people to have the option of upgrading their entry to a "premium" entry by purchasing a yearly premium subscription. (Subscriptions would *ideally* be attached to the entry, not the the member, as it's possible for a member to own more than one entry in the directory).
Is there an add-on (or combination of add-ons) that could accomplish these steps (or something similar):

- Member chooses to upgrade their entry to "premium" and is taken to a payment page where they pay for a one-year subscription.
- Once payment is done, the entry in question is altered to somehow indicate that   it's now "premium" - this could be a custom field, or maybe status (I need to be able to use this field or status as a sort option in Super Search results).
- When member's subscription for any entry is nearly expired, they are emailed a renewal notice with link to payment page to renew subscription.
- Member could see the expiry date of current entry's premium subscription at any time
- If subscription is not renewed, listing is downgraded back to free listing (with custom field or status returned to normal)

I'm aware of **Membrr** (http://www.membrr.com) but I'm worried about reports of slow or non-existent support, and it's for membership subscriptions (whereas my preference is for subscriptions to be associated with entries instead). It may turn out that Membrr is the only way for me to go but I was really hoping to explore alternatives first.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I guess this is too difficult a question to get an answer to? I guess I'll adjust my plans to do it with membrr.

Answer (score 2):

It's relatively new to the market but have a look at [Charge](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/charge) for member billing. Joel is a solid developer and makes great products.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use Stripe as I'm not in the US

Comment: ah that sucks - what about CartThrob then?

Answer (score 0):

[**CartThrob Subscriptions**](https://cartthrob.com/site/product_detail/66513) is an addon for CartThrob2 Pro which gives you subscription payment capabilities.

> **Features**
>
> - Create, sell, and manage subscription plans
> - Customers can update their own subscriptions
> - Create, sell, and manage permissions (ACL-access control levels)
> - Take subscription payments along with product & donation payments in the same transaction
> - Configurable notifications for purchase, rebill success, and rebill failure events
> - Works with many popular payment gateways including Stripe, Authorize.net and eWay
> - Utilizes token/vault based payments. No credit card data is stored on your site.